# How to auto SUM TD value on click event inside TR with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

How to auto SUM `TD` value (with `class="abc"`) when `TR` gets clicked, and result of SUM must be inside a `TD` with `class="total"`.

Below is my HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td class="abc">30</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td class="abc">40</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td class="abc">30</td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td>Bla bla</td>
    <td class="total">100</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

I mean like this: 
[image: Table]

Comment: $('.total').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/frv2U/)</kbd>

```
var total = $('td.total'), //cache your selectors
    td_abc = $('td.abc');
$('tr').click(function () { //handle click event on tr
    total.text(function () { //set total text
        var sum = 0; //set sum to 0
        td_abc.each(function () { //loop through each td element with class abc
            sum += +$(this).text() //add it text to sum
        });
        return sum; //set sum to total
    })
});
```

[Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

[jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/)

---

**Updated After OP's comment**

```
var total = $('td.total'),
    td_abc = $('td.abc');
$('tr').click(function () {
    $(this).find('td.abc').data('countme', 1).css('color', 'red');//set .data('countme', 1) to the td.abc inside tr
    total.text(function () {
        var sum = 0
        td_abc.filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('countme') == 1; //filter elements which has .data('countme', 1) to be added in sum
        }).each(function () {
            sum += +$(this).text()
        });
        return sum;
    })
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/frv2U/1)</kbd>

---

If you want toggle effect.If you click again it not count it in sum .

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/frv2U/2)</kbd>

Comment: @khoir Check Updated answer with demo .

Comment: Nice Answer (y), 
When I click TR again, TOTAL value will decrease.
how to do it?

Comment: Great Answer Tushar Gupta!

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$('tr').click(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('td.abc').each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
  })
  $('td.total').text(sum);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/evB8b/)

Answer (score 2):

I would add a button like: `<button id="sum">Sum</button>` and the use this to sum the values:

```
$('#sum').on('click', function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('table td.abc').each(function () {
        sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
    });
    $('table td.total').html(sum);
});
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4wscw/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just add click event to TR and get all TD values with `class="abc"` and sum them to TD with `class="total"`. Please see below code

```
$("tr").click(function(){
  var total = 0;
  $("td.abc").each(function(){
  total+=parseInt($(this).html()); // You can use parseFloat if value is float.
  });

  $("td.total").html(total);
});
```

Below is the answer after adding image to the quetion.
       
Here we can add a simple CSS `class="clicked"` to td if its parent tr gets clicked (you can add CSS effects like change bg-color to yellow or some color to show if tr is clicked or not) and remove class when it clicked again...
       And on the basis of class="clicked", we will add or remove values from total.

please see below code:

```
$("tr").click(function(){
      var total =  $("td.total").html();

      if(total==null || total=="")
         total = 0;     

      $(this).find(".abc").each(function(){
          var tdCSS = $(this).attr("class");
          if(tdCSS.indexOf("clicked")!=-1)
           { 
              total-=parseInt($(this).html()); // You can use parseFloat if value is float.
           }
           else
           {
             total+=parseInt($(this).html()); // You can use parseFloat if value is float.
           }
            $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
      });

      $("td.total").html(total);
    });
```